# compatability of Desfire EV1/2 readers and cards with a Doorking access control system

Tags: access-control, physical, smartcard

I am getting the idea that Doorking's ProxPlus cards and reader have a pre-defined encryption key in their reader. As these readers are wiegand devices and the software for the Doorking Access systems has no means of doing authentication of an encryption key, I assume my only option may be their proprietary product.

I was hopeful of using an off-the-shelf Desfire EV1/2 reader with precoded cards but it sounds like the software Doorking uses, won't support it.

Does anyone know for sure?

Comment: We can't do product recommendations.

Comment: I'm not looking for a specific product, but are there products out there that will do what I am looking to do? I am trying to discern if I understand the technology correctly. Since the access control unit software doesn't support entering keys, do I need a solution that has a key hard coded in the reader in order for the facility code and card # to be passed to the access control unit via the wiegand interface, and is this information that would be pre-coded into a card?  I amthinking that is what the Doorking ProxPlus reader/cards do?

Comment: I'm referring to your line "Or, are there other encrypted options that are not proprietary, and priced as such?" which I removed.